# Show hide div based on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show hidden div based on radio button input.
When it is checked yes then it should show the hidden div and when checked no, it should hide the div.

I don't know why it is not working. I have checked with some other references on stack, but it didn't help.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='otherppt']").click(function() {
    if ($("#otheryes").is(":checked")) {
      $("#otherdoi").show();
      $("#otherdoi input").prop("required", true);
    } else {
      $("#otherdoi").hide();
      $("#otherdoi input").prop("required", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-group">
  <input type="radio" id="otheryes" name="otherppt" class="other_ppt" required value='yes' data-msg='Please select any one of these.' />
  <input type="radio" id="otherno" name="otherppt" class="other_ppt" required value='no' data-msg="Please choose any one of these." />
</div>
<div class="form-group row" id="otherdoi" style="display:none">
  <div class="col-mobi-12 col-xs-6">
    <label class=""><b>Date of Issue <span>(Day-Month-Year)</span> <span class="txt-red">*</span></b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-mobi-12 col-xs-6 col-md-5">
    <div class="input-append default date dob-dates" data-date="19-03-2019" data-date-format="M dd, yyyy">
      <span class="form-date-field">
        <input type="text" name="date_of_issue" class="required date-of-issue" autocomplete=off readonly data-msg='Please enter date of issue.' placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
         </span>
      <i class="clear">&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `checkbox` has no `click` event. maybe it is better to use `change` event.
`$("input[name='otherppt']").change(function() {...`

Comment: It is working fine for me. Not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ellipsis :  i don't know why it is not working for me. i have checked .change and .click both.

Comment: I just tried your code in JS Bin and everything seems to be working as you require. Probably make sure that you have jquery added in your header or body

Comment: I have edited the question, if you will run the snippet you will notice it is working.

Comment: you code worked fine. cam't able to reproduce

Comment: @shrys converted it to a runable snippet which shows it's working fine (assuming they didn't fix anything in the process, doesn't look like it).  Always try to recreate a [mcve] first.   If it's not working for you, then you have some other issue not presented here (like missing an include)

Comment: *"it is not working"* - can you provide more information as to how it's not working - any errors in the console? wrong div being shown/hidden?

Comment: @freedomn-m - no there is no erros in console,everything is similar as i mentioned here, jquery and jquery migrate is in head. i am surprised it is working here in fiddle but not on my website.

Comment: @OjibixCreatives  give your website URL

Comment: https://www.getyourevisa.com/india-visa2/registration

in this url, there is yes no option.

Comment: use this   $('#radio-group input:radio').click(function() {

Comment: Your website doesn't have the same code as the snippet - you're using a 3rd party wrapper to change the appearance of the radio, so you're not actually `click`ing on the radio at all.

Comment: @freedomn-m - i am not able to understand then, what should i do?

Comment: Depends on what the 3rd party wrapper provides.  Check its API documentation.  I don't recognise `iCheck-helper` so can't guess what wrapper you're using (not obvious from a very quick look at the includes)

Comment: @freedomn-m - thanks for your help, let me go through my codes again.

Comment: @freedomn-m - yes it is iCheck-helper.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have other input[name='otherppt'] in your code. Maybe on different files (widgets/popups)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change','.other_ppt', function() {
   if ($("#otheryes").is(":checked")) {
       $("#otherdoi").show();
       $("#otherdoi input").attr("required", true);
   } else {
       $("#otherdoi").hide();
       $("#otherdoi input").attr("required", false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code working fine may be it is CDN link breakage. Try again

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
  <body>
<div class="radio-group">    
       <input type="radio" id="otheryes" name="otherppt" class="other_ppt" required value='yes' data-msg='Please select any one of these.' />
       <input type="radio" id="otherno" name="otherppt" class="other_ppt" required value='no' data-msg="Please choose any one of these." />
</div>
    <div class="form-group row" id="otherdoi" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-mobi-12 col-xs-6">
    <label class=""><b>Date of Issue <span>(Day-Month-Year)</span> <span class="txt-red">*</span></b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-mobi-12 col-xs-6 col-md-5">
    <div class="input-append default date dob-dates" data-date="19-03-2019" data-date-format="M dd, yyyy">
    <span class="form-date-field">
    <input type="text" name="date_of_issue" class="required date-of-issue" autocomplete=off readonly data-msg='Please enter date of issue.' placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
     </span>
    <i class="clear">&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script>
        $(function() {
            $("input[name='otherppt']").click(function() {
                if ($("#otheryes").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#otherdoi").show();
                    $("#otherdoi input").prop("required", true);
                } else {
                    $("#otherdoi").hide();
                    $("#otherdoi input").prop("required", false);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
   </body>

 </html>
```